What could be the best approach to implement TTL in a column in postgres/RDBMS?
I have a system which stores date of joining in postgres DB. There is also a award category code in the same table which looks like:
NO_AWARD - when employee has spent less than 1 year
How to implement a solution where remove the NO_AWARD code once any employee completes 1 year. Employees join throughout the year.
One solution can be run a scheduled job which scans the table and nullify the category code column.
What other options can be be considered?
Thanks in advance.

Does this answer your question? Is there a way to set an "expiry" time, after which a data entry is automatically deleted in PostgreSQL? (Check the highest rated comment of the highest rated answer!)

I would say the cron solution would be the way to go. Either as actually using an external cron job or by using one of the Postgres extension that do this; pg_timetable or pg_cron.

@maraca, thanks for the suggestion. I have checked it already and I know that psql does not support TTL. I was wondering if there are better design approach available other than the one i listed. For e.g another approach: instead of scanning table everyday, maintain a table to store the date when is the earliest date for an expiry and scan.

It depends. I would go for the one with best maintainability. E.g. choose the one that most people in your company can work with and document it properly. And keep it simple, another table would introduce more overhead than benefit imho.

A job might run fewer times with another table, but is it really an advantage? If the job doesn't run for some reason and misses records it is not corrected the next day. Also you have to implement that logic first. Harder to maintain for little to no benefit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Don't store NO_AWARD.
select
  -- other columns
  case
    when employee.start_date > current_date - interval '1 year' then 'NO_AWARD'
    else award_code
  end as award_code
from -- whatever


this will only work for a read operation. There can be a use case when behind the scene need to nullify or update with some other code when appropriate time comes. For e.g congratulations notification when 1 year completed. What I am trying to identify daily/weekly/monthly which records are eligible with minimum scan/search

For updates, add and start_date < current_date - interval '1 year' to the where clause. Or, do everything in the app layer (if there is one).
